# Can you guess what am I?

Tags: riddle, movies

> I am a song, 
>  I am also a movie.
>  And I am the recommended
>   answer to the Lord of Death.

What am I?

HINT:

> I am comprised of two words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you

> Not today ?

I am a song,

> [Not today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Today_%28Mary_J._Blige_song%29) (Mary J. Blige song)

I am also a movie.

> [Not today (movie)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1564870/)

And I am the recommended answer to the Lord of Death.

> - What do you say to the Lord of death ?
>  - [Not today](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/471315-what-do-we-say-to-the-lord-of-death-not)

HINT :

> It is 2 words

Comment: That's not fair...You are the lord of dark. You already knew the questions and some of the answers.

Comment: You will be good on roman emperors question, so that's fair ! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_Aurelius_Marius

Comment: It was easy, right? Well, it was my first attempt. Feedback is appreciated :)

Comment: @CinCout The two first lines are very very broad, almost everything is a song and/or a movie.

Comment: But the third one is a real deal-breaker. No?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to add a series of answers that fit this patterns (I think).
Here is the first one. Not probably what you expect but I'll take my chances.

> Final Destination

I am a song,

> [Final Destination - Within Temptation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggLkWIrbWWQ)

I am also a movie.

> [Final Destination](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0195714/?ref_=nv_sr_2)

And I am the recommended answer to the Lord of Death.

> For some cultures: Q: "Do you know where you are?". A: "I've reached my final destination".

**Second attempt:**

> Go now
>  [Go now - the moody blues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h42kzEA9l8Q)
>  [Go now the movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113184/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)

**Third one:**

> Goodbye Girl
>  [Goodbye Girl - David Gates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MaczkqNPBI)
>  [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076095/?ref_=nv_sr_1)
>  That's what I would say to the Lord of death.

**Forth One:**

> Happy Together
>  [Happy Together - The Turtles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sZ6K9r7qcY)
>  Movie [Happy together](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118845/?ref_=nv_sr_1)
>  ..well :)

**Fifth**

> Poor Cow
>  [Poor Cow - Donovan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EmH1a4IZBsk)
>  [Movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062141/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)

**6:**

> Stayin' Alive
>  [Stayin' Alive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Vj092UgKwQ)
>  [Movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086361/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

Comment: Loving the third attempt!

Comment: TIL that the Lord of Death is a female!

Comment: @CinCout. He/She/It does not need to be a female in order to tell him/her/it "Goodbye Girl". Just read it in the voice of a bitchy 17 yo cheerleader.

Comment: I guess I took the word 'girl' too literally.

Comment: To the person(s) who donvotes this...what's wrong with my answer. Let me know so I won't do it in the future.